# Two Videos with Two Modals

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a site that content with a link that pops up to a modal. That model has two videos which in facts pops up with own modal.

Here's url:
falconcropprotection.com

From the top menu, click on Case Studies. It will scroll down the case studies. Select the first one on the left called Fawnridge Winery and Vineyards.

A model will popup. On the right at the top is the first video. Click on that video. Another modal opens up. Close that model. Now scroll down a bit and click on the second video and it will too pop up into a modal. Both work fine. Go ahead and close that popup.

Now go back to the first video and click on that. The modal pops up but now the video is missing. What I notice is the the URL for that first iframe seems to be removed after closing. That doesn't happen with the second one.

Here's my script. I am sure it's something I did wrong.  I am using this script so that it will kill the video should anyone close the modal before the video is done. Otherwise you will still hear the audio and I don't want that.

```
<script>
  $('.close-modal-1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.video-embed').children('iframe').attr('src', '');
  });
</script>
<script>
  $('.close-modal-2').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.video-embed-2').children('iframe').attr('src', '');
  });
</script>
```

Here's my html for the two video buttons:

```
<button class="imagebtn" data-toggle="modal" href="#CaseStudy77YT">
<img alt="" src="/news/images/content/youtube-thumb.jpg" /></button>

<button class="imagebtn" data-toggle="modal" href="#CaseStudy77YT2">
<img alt="" src="/news/images/content/youtube-thumb-2.jpg" /></button>
```

Here's the HTML for both modals:

```
<div id="CaseStudy77YT" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first" style="margin:50px auto auto; max-width:960px; max-height:680px;background :#f9f9f9;">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn close close-modal-1">Close</button>

        <h3>Good Morning Sacramento</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body video-embed">
        <iframe width="910" height="510" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/T9W3SEo0za4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>         </div>
</div>

<div id="CaseStudy77YT2" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first" style="margin:50px auto auto; max-width:960px; max-height:680px;background :#f9f9f9;">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn close close-modal2">Close</button>

        <h3>FrightKite Over Golden Gate Field</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body video-embed-2">
        <iframe width="910" height="510" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/FG9fgVVGoe0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>         </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please add your html code, why are you using different classes for each video and each modal? if is for naming purposes, use `name` or `id`

Comment: Hi. Thank you for responding. I have updated my original post to show the HTML buttons and models.  FYI:  I am not that savvy when it comes to jquery. When you provide or make a suggestion you will need to be precise so that I can understand what it is I need to do. Thank you.

Comment: No solution? I know it's an odd situation but I am hoping there is a work around.  Thank you.

Comment: it disappear, because your code delete it from the DOM `$('.video-embed').children('iframe').attr('src', '');` you have to reassign the src if you want to re-open the modal... It doesn't delete the src in the second modal video because your code adds the event to the class: `$('.close-modal-2')...` and the code in the page is `close-modal2`... but is it really necessary to delete the src?

Comment: What happens is that when you close the modal before the video is finished playing you will still hear the video in the background. And so that is the solution I was given to overcome that. However, this was based on one video which was before I decided to add a second one.

As for the second video 'close-modal-2', my bad. It was a typo on my part. However, the second video is not a problem because it has no sound in the first place (intentional).  

I hope to find a solution to keep the video from playing once the modal is closed.   Thank you.